# How to get the list of newly created files during an application instance in a certain directory?

Tags: c#, file, directory, filesystemwatcher

I would like to know how I can get the list of newly created files during an application instance in a certain directory when my application was open.

Just to be clear: Every time my application is opened, few files get generated in a certain directory, I want the list of only those files which got created after the application was opened.

Comment: store application opened time when opened, check files created after this time

Comment: You need to get the files modified after a specif-c time.             DateTime date = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);
            DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp");

            List<FileInfo> filesInfo = dirInfo.GetFiles().Where(x => x.LastWriteTime >= date).ToList();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use FileWatcher

```
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    watcher.Path = @"C:\temp";
    watcher.NotifyFilter =  NotifyFilters.FileName;
    watcher.Filter = "*.*";
    watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    private static void OnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"File created {e.Name}");
    }
```